# How to add a button to a frame from a separate class?

Tags: java, class, jbutton

```
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class EventButton extends MainLayout{
        //create the string for the button's text 
        private String button_text; 
        private JButton event_button; 
        private JPanel event_panel;



        public EventButton(){
            //initialize the button text
            button_text = "Set Event";
            event_button = new JButton();
            event_panel = new JPanel();
            event_button.setText(button_text);
            event_panel.add(event_button);
            add(event_panel);



        }
}


import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainLayout extends JFrame{
    public MainLayout(){
        EventButton eb = new EventButton();
    }
}


import javax.swing.*;
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MainLayout frame = new MainLayout();
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Those are the three separate classes. Right now I want to be able to add the button to the MainLayout frame but can't seem to figure it out. When I run this code I get an error and I've tried different things like creating the instance of the button inside the main function, the code compiles but only a frame pops up.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like instead of having `EventButton` extend `MainLayout` (which won't work because it would be a separate instance anyway), what you want to do is this:

```
// Change the EventButton() constructor:
public EventButton(Container addTo) {
   ...
   addTo.add(event_panel);
}

// Change your MainLayout() constructor:
public MainLayout(){
   EventButton eb = new EventButton(getContentPane());
}
```

Comment: The constructor EventButton(Container) is undefined